# how does following for loop work ? for (String temp : uniqueSet)

Tags: java

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(list);
for (String temp : uniqueSet) {
    System.out.println(temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, temp));
}
```

Above is the java code that i got from one of the forum, the for loop was looking little mysterious, can some one please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a for-each loop.

This is actually equivalent to :

```
for (Iterator<String> i = uniqueSet.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
        String temp = i.next();
        System.out.println(temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, temp));
}
```

You can find more informations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).